# NullPointer with Primefaces GMap OverlaySelect event

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-gmap

I have a problem with Primefaces whose  version is 3.0.M3 .
I used gmap and prime p:ajax.I wanted to do something is to get clicked Marker when a marker is clicked by a user on Gmap.

Here is the Code

```
<p:tabView effect="slide" effectDuration="normal" style="width:1050px;height:450px" >
            <p:tab title="blabla">
                <h:panelGrid colums="1">    
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="blabla" >
                <h:panelGrid colums="1">
                    <h:form id="mapId">

                        <p:gmap  id="asd" center="39.000409,35.201554" 
                            zoom="#{mapBean.modelMap.zoomLevel}" 
                            type="ROADMAP" 
                            style="width:1000px;height:400px"
                            model="#{mapBean.emptyModel}"
                            widgetVar="map" >

                            <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{mapBean.onMarkerSelect}"/>

                        </p:gmap>

                    </h:form>   
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab></p:tabView>
```

and My ManagedBean

```
public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event) {  

    Marker marker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
    if (marker!=null) {
        System.out.println(marker.getId());
    }
    System.out.println("Clicked");
    modelMap.setZoomLevel(modelMap.getZoomLevel()+1);

}
```

Managed Bean Declarations

```
@ManagedBean(name="mapBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MapBean implements Serializable
```

I am taking `NullPointerException` in `onMarkerSelect` method.(`event.getOverlay();`)

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to M4 or RC1?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Tried several primefaces version (all from 3.1 to 3.3) I have the same problem with all of them.

Answer (score 6):

Fixed my problem.

The problem was that when the `MapModel` was created it was a local var:

```
public MapModel getModel() {

    final MapModel mapModel = new DefaultMapModel(); // this should be a field

    final Set<MapEventDto> events = service.loadEvents();
    for (MapEventDto event : events) {

        final double latitude = event.getLatitude().doubleValue();
        final double longitude = event.getLongitude().doubleValue();
        final String magnitude = event.getMagnitude().toString();

        final String title = "Id: " + event.getId() + ", Lat: " + latitude + ", Lng: " + longitude + ", Mag: " + magnitude;

        mapModel.addOverlay(new Marker(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), title));

    }
    return mapModel;
}
```

The whole `mapModel` could be garbage collected after the map is rendered (as it is no longer needed). So when the overlay event is called there would be no `mapModel` any more.

As soon as I made `mapModel` a field of the `Bean` the problem disappeared.

Comment: If someone else could also test this I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: The general rule in JSF is that getters/setters should **not** do anything else than doing *just* the job they're named for: getting and setting a property. Preparing the data should be done in the (post)constructor or a (action)listener method or at highest lazy loading in the getter. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Answer (score 3):

Use the `static` field as follows.
It worked for me.

```
final static MapModel mapModel = new DefaultMapModel();
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, static fields should not represent state, as you pave the way for a lot of head aches.

Answer (score 0):

```
final DefaultMapModel mapModel = new DefaultMapModel();
```

worked For as Global Variable,in viewScoped
best
vj

Answer (score 0):

Got through this and solved by changing scope for the Bean to `ViewScoped` instead of Request Scope, so it lasts during user activity.

No final/static declarators needed

```
  @ManagedBean(name="mapBean")
  @ViewScoped
  public class MapBean implements Serializable {  
    private MapModel draggableModel;   
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your bean scope to `@SessionScoped` or `@ViewScoped` so your bean won't be initialized for each request.